# How can I fix PrnScrn behaviour in rider?

Tags: windows, rider

When the Rider window is in focus, the prnscrn button does not take screenshots. I have used several screenshot applications. There is just nothing happening. When I take the focus away from the rider window, like clicking on the taskbar or another window, the screenshots start taking as intended. I can't find anything in the rider settings, as well as in keybindings.